# Is It possible to keep a running timer in a database?

Tags: c#, sql, time, timer, stopwatch

Is it possible to keep a running timer in a database?

For example. Lets say I created a timer entity with that would be able to hold individual records of running timers?

To my best understanding things stored in a database have to be static. So is there a way to keep a non-static record in a db?

Comment: you could update a value in the database on an interval, I wouldn't recommend this, but that's the only way it would work

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @John I am trying to develop an MVC application that would allow a user to create timers which will be running and stored in a SQL db. I'm aware there are other and probably better ways to do this, but I'm trying to attempt it this way first.

Comment: What do you want this timer to do? Are you trying to cause something to happen when the timer "hits zero"? If so, what kind of action do you want to happen? Or, are you just trying to find the time elapsed since the timer was started, like a stopwatch?

Comment: @Scott More of a stopwatch. Timers countdown but I want this to show time passed like a stopwatch. So I will be using the stopwatch class not the timer class.

Comment: Why do you want a _running_ timer in the database. Why does it actually need to _run_? Or, do you simply need to be able to retrieve the _current running time_ at any given instant? I think you're assuming that the timer needs to be running in order to know how long it has been running.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware now that the timer doesn't need to actually be running since you can just use the elapsed time since the timer was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the stopwatch class in .NET does is writes down the time when you start the stopwatch then when you look at the result it just subtracts the start time from the stop/current time.

It would be as simple as

```
create table Stopwatches
(
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    StartTime DateTime not null,
    EndTime DateTime null
)
```

To start a stopwatch

```
insert into Stopwatches (StartTime) values (GetDate())
select @@IDENTITY as StopwatchId;
```

To stop a stopwatch

```
update Stopwatches
set EndTime = GetDate()
where id = @stopwatchId
```

To view the time elapsed

```
select DateDiff(second, StartTime, EndTime) as Elapsed where id = @stopwatchId
```

Answer (score 1):

use virtual table

try this

http://sqlite.org/lang_createvtab.html

it explains their about virtual tables but i dont think you can do non-static in db